# how to assign new values to elements of a List using if else in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to return a list of tuples from a list of string after pattern matching using if else. I'm new to Scala so I don't now how to use pattern match yet.

Data:

```
val foodOrder: List[String] = List(mealOne, mealTwo, mealThree, mealFour, mealFive, mealOne, mealTwo, mealThree)

val mealOne =   ( "Burger and chips", 4.99)

val mealTwo =   ( "Pasta & Chicken with Chips", 8.99)

val mealThree = ( "Pasta & Chicken with Salad", 8.99)

val mealFour =  ( "Rice & Chicken with Chips", 8.99)

val mealFive =  ( "Rice & Chicken with Salad", 8.99)
```

Solution:

```
def stringToItem(order: List[String]): (String, Double) = {

for (order <- orders) {

    if(order == mealOne) {

        mealOne
        stringToItem(foodOrder)

        } else if(order == mealTwo) {

        mealTwo
        stringToItem(foodOrder)
        } else if(order == mealThree) {

        mealThree
        stringToItem(foodOrder)
        } else if(order == mealFour) {

        mealFour
        stringToItem(foodOrder)
        } else if(order == mealFive) {

        meal
        stringToItem(foodOrder)
        } else {

        noMeal
        stringToItem(foodOrder)
        }
  }
}
```

Desired result:
`List ( ( "Burger and chips", 4.99), ( "Pasta & Chicken with Chips", 8.99), ( "Pasta & Chicken with Salad", 8.99), ( "Rice & Chicken with Chips", 8.99), ( "Rice & Chicken with Salad", 8.99), ( "Burger and chips", 4.99), ( "Pasta & Chicken with Chips", 8.99), ( "Pasta & Chicken with Salad", 8.99) )`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here: `fooOrder` already _is_ your "desired result".

Comment: `foodOrder` wouldn't be a `List[String]` even if it compiled. Looks more like a `List[(String, Double)]`. Please edit it into an [mcve].

Comment: Mike, @AndreyTyukin is correct your output type is not List[String], also why do you want to do pattern matching only, there are other ways also to solve this.

Comment: @zenwraight can you show me how please

Comment: @Andrey will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have input stored as a map of `String -> (String, Double)`.

So your input will look like this:-

```
val mapFoodToPrice: Map[String, (String, Double)] = Map("mealOne" -> ("Burger and chips", 4.99),
                                                        "mealTwo" -> ("Pasta & Chicken with Chips", 8.99),
                                                        "mealThree" -> ("Pasta & Chicken with Salad", 8.99),
                                                        "mealFour" -> ("Rice & Chicken with Chips", 8.99),
                                                        "mealFive" -> ("Rice & Chicken with Salad", 8.99))
```

Now You have this which you need to execute:-

```
val foodOrder: List[String] = List("mealOne", "mealTwo", "mealThree", "mealFour"
  , "mealFive", "mealOne", "mealTwo", "mealThree")
```

Now Here is the computation logic to get the desired Result:-

```
val result = foodOrder.map { foodName =>
  mapFoodToPrice.get(foodName).get
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help. can you explain how the solution works in particular flatmap and get methods.

Comment: So, when you do .get() on a map, it returns you Option[(String, Double)] , so in short you will be getting List[Option[(String, Double)]] and I use get(), to get the value out of option.